# How to Open textfile in two different databases

Tags: database, vba, ms-access, vb6

I'm writing a code to see what the possibilties are by creating a certain text file to and link it to a tabel in MS-access.

```
Sub Testtxt()
 Open "C:\test.txt" For Output Shared As #1
  Write #1, "A1"
  Write #1, "B1"
  Write #1, "C1"
  Write #1, "D1"
  Write #1, "E1"

 Close #1
 End Sub
```

Comment: Where are you stuck? have you used the Get External Data menu item? How about DoCmd.transferText?

Comment: I'm trying to use 1 textfile in two different Ms-access databases at the same time.

Comment: Yes. What problem are you experiencing? You can link, but you cannot open in two databases at the same time.

Comment: If I link a table to the textfile "test.txt" in database1, I can open the textfile and edit the data. I linked a table in database2 to the same textfile "test.txt". But when I try to open the textfile while the textfile is in use by 1 of both databases i get an errornumber 3051. Is there a way to use the same textfile at the same time in both databases with a linked table?

Comment: No. Why would you want to? Use a table instead, then both users can update.

Answer (score 1):

If your question is : (How can I allow two different databases to read a single text file?) then that is as easy as

```
Dim MyLine as String
Open "c:\myfile.txt" For Input As #1
   Do While Not Eof(1)
       Line input #1, myLine
       'Do whatever here
   Loop
Close #1
```

However, if your question is (How can I allow two different databases to write to the same text file?) then you can't. The first database that holds access to WRITE to the file will block the second database from doing so and your code will report some Access denied error or something like that. So it is a race. You should write your code so that the second database will wait for the file to be closed by the first database then proceeding to write to it (Which I guess will be useless since from your code you don't append to the file, but overwrite it) so the previous data written by the first database will be lost.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Because of the write block it's not possible to do it this way.